# Immutable numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, immutability, readonly

Is there a simple way to create an immutable NumPy array?

If one has to derive a class from `ndarray` to do this, what's the minimum set of methods that one has to override to achieve immutability?

Comment: Why do you need immutability?

Comment: @KennyTM To avoid coding errors caused by accidentally modifying something that's assumed invariant.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You can make a numpy array unwriteable:

```
a = np.arange(10)
a.flags.writeable = False
a[0] = 1
# Gives: ValueError: assignment destination is read-only
```

Also see the discussion in this thread:

http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2008-December/039274.html

and the documentation:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flags.html

Comment: Alternatively, `a.setflags(write=False)`.

Comment: @lafrasu Which would you say is the preferred form, `setflags()` or `flags.writeable=`?

Comment: @aix: A quick look at the documentation would make it seem as if the two approaches are identical. Personally, I prefer using a method to set attributes.

Comment: Does this also make it memoizable?

Comment: IMPORTANT!! Numpy DOES NOT have an immutable array. Arrays with `.flags.writeable = False` are still not immutable.
If `x` is an array, `y = x[:]; x.flags.writeable = False; y[0] = 5` updates the first element of `x` to `5`.

Comment: @JamesParker you do get an error if you set the writeable flag before creating `y`.

Comment: @JamesParker It seems the flags come with the array when you slice. So if the `writable` flag is set to `False` *before* you slice then then `y` above would fail on update.

Comment: @DamonMaria I tested it and that seems to be correct. You can only change `y.flags.writeable = True` when that value for `x` is true. It's just changing `writeable` for `x` does not update that of `y` directly.

Comment: @James Parker apparently the order is important. A slice before setting writable to False, is not blocked. “...locking a base object does not lock any views that already reference it”. See under `writable` tag
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flags.html

Comment: FYI, I used ```arr.flags.writeable = False```, but then I called ```for i in range(5): np.random.shuffle(arr[:,i])```, which shuffled the array in place - no errors or warnings.

Comment: @Joe strange, I just tried it and I get an error...

Comment: @Vinzent, sorry, my comment was missing an important detail - I used `arr = np.arange(30).reshape(6,5)`.  If you tried `for i in range(5): np.random.shuffle(arr[:,i])` on `arr = np.arange(10)` you would definitely get an `IndexError`.

Comment: It seems that cv2 ignores this flag. I put it on an image so I force myself to remember doing frame.copy() before drawing on it, but cv2.line(frame, ...) doesn't throw an error.

```
a = np.zeros((FRAME_HEIGHT, FRAME_WIDTH, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
a.setflags(write=False)
cv2.line(a, (100, 100), (200, 200), (255, 255, 255), 10)

cv2_imshow(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the flag directly didn't work for me, but using [`ndarray.setflags`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.setflags.html) did work:

```py
a = np.arange(10)
a.setflags(write=False)
a[0] = 1  # ValueError
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a subclass of Array at this gist: https://gist.github.com/sfaleron/9791418d7023a9985bb803170c5d93d8

It makes a copy of its argument and marks that as read-only, so you should only be able to shoot yourself in the foot if you are very deliberate about it. My immediate need was for it to be hashable, so I could use them in sets, so that works too. It isn't a lot of code, but about 70% of the lines are for testing, so I won't post it directly.

Note that it's not a drop-in replacement; it won't accept any keyword args like a normal Array constructor. Instances will behave like Arrays, though.