# Repeat NumPy array without replicating data?

Tags: python, numpy, memory, large-data

I'd like to create a 1D NumPy array that would consist of 1000 back-to-back repetitions of another 1D array, without replicating the data 1000 times.

Is it possible?

If it helps, I intend to treat both arrays as immutable.

Comment: I came across this question after trying to search for large-data manipulation in Python. I read about Strides and was wondering why would need a replicated data which is essentially the same (points to same data in the memory). You can read read from single data set twice, can't you? I just want to know the reason you are doing this replication. Thanks.

Comment: I feel like a lot of times you might want to do this, what you *really* want to do is use broadcasting.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can't do this; a NumPy array must have a consistent stride along each dimension, while your strides would need to go one way most of the time but sometimes jump backwards.

The closest you can get is either a 1000-row 2D array where every row is a view of your first array, or a [`flatiter` object](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatiter.html), which behaves kind of like a 1D array. (flatiters support iteration and indexing, but you can't take views of them; all indexing makes a copy.)

Setup:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)
```

2D view:

```
b = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, (1000, a.size), (0, a.itemsize))
```

flatiter object:

```
c = b.flat
```

Comment: Cool, I was wondering if strides could be used, but I couldn't figure out how! `b.flat` or `b.flatten()`?

Comment: `b.flat.base is b` is True; `b.flatten().base is b` is False, so you want `b.flat`

Comment: Not sure what that means. `b.flatten().base` returns nothing... `(b.flat == b.flatten()).all()` is True, so what is the difference?

Comment: see  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.base.html. The difference is that your comparison tests if the values are the same on an element-wise basis. `.base` tells you about ownership of data.

Answer (score 19):

[`broadcast_to`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) was added in numpy 1.10, which allows you effectively repeat an array with a little less effort.

Copying the style of the accepted answer:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(10)
repeated = np.broadcast_to(arr, (1000, arr.size))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by 'not replicating the data 1000 times'. If you are looking for a numpy method to build `b` from `a` in one fell swoop (rather than looping), you can use:

```
a = np.arange(1000)
b = np.tile(a,1000)
```

Otherwise, I would do something like:

```
a = np.arange(1000)
ii = [700,2000,10000] # The indices you want of the tiled array
b = a[np.mod(ii,a.size)]
```

`b` is not a view of `a` in this case because of the fancy indexing (it makes a copy), but at least it returns a numpy array and doesn't create the 1000*1000x1 array in memory and just contains the elements you want.

As far as them being immutable (see [Immutable numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541324/immutable-numpy-array/5541452#5541452)), you would need to switch the flag for each separately since copies don't retain the flag setting.

Answer (score 0):

I do not claim that this is the most elegant solution, because you have to fool numpy into creating an array of objects (see the line with the comment)

```
from numpy import array

n = 3

a = array([1,2])
a.setflags(write=False)
t = [a]*n + [array([1])] # Append spurious array that is not len(a)
r = array(t,dtype=object)
r.setflags(write=False)

assert id(a) == id(t[1]) == id(r[1])
```

Answer (score -1):

Would this work:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
b = numpy.ones((1000, a.shape[0]))
b *= a
b = b.flatten()
```

Comment: This seems like a very expensive way of doing things if you are going to produce a copy, and is ~15x slower than just using `np.tile`