# Python: optimising loops

Tags: python, loops, numpy

I wish to optimise some python code consisting of two nested loops.  I am not so familar with numpy, but I understand it should enable me to improve the efficiency for such a task.  Below is a test code I wrote that reflects what happens in the actual code.  Currently using the numpy range and iterator is slower than the usual python one.  What am I doing wrong?  What is the best solution to this problem?

Thanks for your help!

```
import numpy
import time

# setup a problem analagous to that in the real code
npoints_per_plane = 1000
nplanes = 64
naxis = 1000
npoints3d = naxis + npoints_per_plane * nplanes
npoints = naxis + npoints_per_plane
specres = 1000

# this is where the data is being mapped to
sol = dict()
sol["ems"] = numpy.zeros(npoints3d)
sol["abs"] = numpy.zeros(npoints3d)

# this would normally be non-random input data
data = dict()
data["ems"] = numpy.zeros((npoints,specres))
data["abs"] = numpy.zeros((npoints,specres))
for ip in range(npoints):
    data["ems"][ip,:] = numpy.random.random(specres)[:]
    data["abs"][ip,:] = numpy.random.random(specres)[:]
ems_mod = numpy.random.random(1)[0]
abs_mod = numpy.random.random(1)[0]
ispec = numpy.random.randint(specres)

# this the code I want to optimize

t0 = time.time()

# usual python range and iterator
for ip in range(npoints_per_plane):
    jp = naxis + ip
    for ipl in range(nplanes):
        ip3d = jp + npoints_per_plane * ipl
        sol["ems"][ip3d] = data["ems"][jp,ispec] * ems_mod
        sol["abs"][ip3d] = data["abs"][jp,ispec] * abs_mod

t1 = time.time()

# numpy ranges and iterator
ip_vals = numpy.arange(npoints_per_plane)
ipl_vals = numpy.arange(nplanes)
for ip in numpy.nditer(ip_vals):
    jp = naxis + ip
    for ipl in numpy.nditer(ipl_vals):
        ip3d = jp + npoints_per_plane * ipl
        sol["ems"][ip3d] = data["ems"][jp,ispec] * ems_mod
        sol["abs"][ip3d] = data["abs"][jp,ispec] * abs_mod


t2 = time.time()

print "plain python: %0.3f seconds" % ( t1 - t0 )
print "numpy: %0.3f seconds" % ( t2 - t1 )
```

edit: put "jp = naxis + ip" in the first for loop only

additional note:

I worked out how to get numpy to quickly do the inner loop, but not the outer loop:

```
# numpy vectorization
for ip in xrange(npoints_per_plane):
    jp = naxis + ip
    sol["ems"][jp:jp+npoints_per_plane*nplanes:npoints_per_plane] = data["ems"][jp,ispec] * ems_mod
    sol["abs"][jp:jp+npoints_per_plane*nplanes:npoints_per_plane] = data["abs"][jp,ispec] * abs_mod
```

Joe's solution below shows how to do both together, thanks!

Comment: I'm not acquainted with `numpy.range`, but using Python's `range` is the same as creating a list of `n` elements, whereas, `xrange` is a generator of numbers -- avoiding storage of an entire list.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, but when I use xrange instead of range there is no change in the runtime.

Comment: The key to writing fast numpy code is *avoiding* loops by vectorizing operations (or, rather, pushing the loops down to the fast C level), not that iterating over numpy objects is faster.  IOW, idiomatic numpy code doesn't have many `for` loops, but acts on vectors and arrays as a whole.

Comment: 2 questions. 1) Is the size of the arrays the same as for your true application? 2) How fast do you need the code to run?

Comment: 1) for a small problem, yes.  For the largest problem, it would be more like npoints_per_plane = 50000, nplanes = 64, naxis = 1000, specres = 1000. 2) I want the code to run in a similar order of magnitude to c.  I have just spent a week converting a swig interface to pure python but now it takes twice as long for a small problem, and this is the bottleneck.

Comment: It seems like a simple transform with a constant multiplication for all values. It might be faster to simply write a smart indexer unless you absolutely need the data in a linear array i.e. make 'sol' a class with access operators that access 'data' underneath

Comment: sol is actually a variable in a netcdf file that I am interacting with via netCDF4, so I am currently stuck with a linear array.

Answer (score 6):

The best way of writing loops in numpy is *not* writing loops and instead using vectorized operations. For example:

```
c = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    c += a[i] + b[i]
```

becomes

```
c = np.sum(a + b, axis=0)
```

For `a` and `b` with a shape of `(100000, 100)` this takes 0.344 seconds in the first variant, and 0.062 seconds in the second.

In the case presented in your question the following does what you want:

```
sol['ems'][naxis:] = numpy.ravel(
    numpy.repeat(
        data['ems'][naxis:,ispec,numpy.newaxis] * ems_mod,
        nplanes,
        axis=1
    ),
    order='F'
)
```

This could be further optimized with [some tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564098/repeat-numpy-array-without-replicating-data), but that would reduce clarity and is probably premature optimization because:

> plain python: 0.064 seconds
>
> numpy: 0.002 seconds

The solution works as follows:

Your original version contains `jp = naxis + ip` which merely skips the first `naxis` elements `[naxis:]` selects all but the first naxis elements. Your inner loop repeats the value of `data[jp,ispec]` for `nplanes` times and writes it to multiple locations `ip3d = jp + npoints_per_plane * ipl` which is equivalent to a flattened 2D array offset by `naxis`. Therefore a second dimension is added via `numpy.newaxis` to the (previously 1D) `data['ems'][naxis:, ispec]`, the values are repeated `nplanes` times along this new dimension via `numpy.repeat`. The resulting 2D array is then flattened again via `numpy.ravel` (in Fortran order, i.e., with the lowest axis having the smallest stride) and written to the appropriate subarray of `sol['ems']`. If the target array was actually 2D, the repeat could be skipped by using automatic array broadcasting.

If you run into a situation where you cannot avoid using loops, you could use [Cython](http://cython.org/) (which supports [efficient buffer views](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) on numpy arrays).

Comment: thanks, yeah I am reading http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html to try and work out if I can vectorize my loop.  The problem is it is not a 1:1 mapping so perhaps I need the loop still.  And can I put cython code in a python script?  Not sure how that works...

Comment: Actually the code does look like a one to one mapping, except that it is [`reshape`d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html). Cython code can be used inline via [`cython.inline`](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html#compiling-with-cython-inline).

Comment: how does one vectorize "for i in range(len(a)): c += a[i] + b[2*i]" for example?  this would help me understand what to do.

Comment: `c = numpy.sum(a + b[::2])`

Comment: okay, I see the syntax now ([i:j:k] where i=start, j=stop, k=increment), but I cannot work out how to apply this my loop. how does one vectorize "for ipl in xrange(nplanes): sol["ems"][jp + npoints_per_plane * ipl] = data["ems"][jp,ispec] * ems_mod" for example?

Comment: thanks joe, your solution is both neat and fast (and correct, determined via assert) - exactly why I want to use python!  now I just need to work out how your solution works!

Comment: @user1334640 added some more explanation, hope it helps

Comment: @user1334640 Is more clarification required? If not it would be appropriate to accepted the answer.