# python - repeating numpy array without replicating data

Tags: python, numpy, memory, large-data

This question has been asked before, but the solution only works for 1D/2D arrays, and I need a more general answer.

How do you create a repeating array without replicating the data? This strikes me as something of general use, as it would help to vectorize python operations without the memory hit.

More specifically, I have a (y,x) array, which I want to tile multiple times to create a (z,y,x) array. I can do this with numpy.tile(array, (nz,1,1)), but I run out of memory. My specific case has x=1500, y=2000, z=700.

Comment: What are you going to do with larger array?  `array[None,:,:]` may be just as useful as the tiled array.  Unless you do some sort of `dot` product on the y or x dimension, you could still end up with memory error.

Comment: I have to apply a geographical mask to a geophysical dataset in the form (time, y, x). The module I'm using requires that the mask be the same shape as the dataset, which is why I need to replicate the (y,x) mask onto the time dimension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple trick is to use `np.broadcast_arrays` to broadcast your `(x, y)` against a `z`-long vector in the first dimension:

```
import numpy as np

M = np.arange(1500*2000).reshape(1500, 2000)
z = np.zeros(700)

# broadcasting over the first dimension
_, M_broadcast = np.broadcast_arrays(z[:, None, None], M[None, ...])

print M_broadcast.shape, M_broadcast.flags.owndata
# (700, 1500, 2000), False
```

To generalize the `stride_tricks` method given for a 1D array in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5568169/1461210), you just need to include the shape and stride length for each dimension of your output array:

```
M_strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
                M,                              # input array
                (700, M.shape[0], M.shape[1]),  # output dimensions
                (0, M.strides[0], M.strides[1]) # stride length in bytes
            )
```

Comment: The broadcasting thing does exactly what I wanted. It seems to me as simpler/more logical than the stride_tricks method.

Comment: Internally `broadcast_arrays` uses `as_strided` in exactly this way. Look in `numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py`.  It's the `0` stride length for the first dimension that does the trick.

Comment: The `stride length in bytes` line should be `(0, M.strides[0], M.strides[1])`

Comment: @hpaulj that's interesting to know, although I'm sure that that using `stride_tricks` directly is still more efficient than allocating  another array just to broadcast against.

Comment: `M[None,:,:]` has `shape: (1,...)` and `strides: (0,..)`.  Same strides, but just a `1` in the new shape dimension.

Comment: @ali_m How would you perform further calculations on the broadcast array? even doing an inplace calculation would result in a new array, wouldn't it? for example `np.abs`

Comment: @ali_m I would like to for example reduce the broadcast result over an axis, after some calculation. How would I do that?