# Numpy Cyclic Broadcast of Fancy Indexing

Tags: python, numpy, broadcast

`A` is an `numpy` array with shape `(6, 8)`

I want:

```
x_id = np.array([0, 3])
y_id = np.array([1, 3, 4, 7])

A[ [x_id, y_id] += 1  # this doesn't actually work.
```

Tricks like `::2` won't work because the indices do not increase regularly.

I don't want to use extra memory to repeat `[0, 3]` and make a new array `[0, 3, 0, 3]` because that is slow.

The indices for the two dimensions do not have equal length.

which is equivalent to:

```
A[0, 1] += 1
A[3, 3] += 1
A[0, 4] += 1
A[3, 7] += 1
```

Can `numpy` do something like this?

Update:

Not sure if `broadcast_to` or `stride_tricks` is faster than nested python loops. ([Repeat NumPy array without replicating data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564098/repeat-numpy-array-without-replicating-data))

Comment: hope exists: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564098/repeat-numpy-array-without-replicating-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `y_id` to a 2d array with the 2nd dimension the same as `x_id`, and then the two indices will be automatically broadcasted due to the dimension difference:

```
x_id = np.array([0, 3])
y_id = np.array([1, 3, 4, 7])
​
A = np.zeros((6,8))
A[x_id, y_id.reshape(-1, x_id.size)] += 1 

A
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: Sounds wonderful... The actual array is 6 dimensional. Let me try that.