# immutable numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

My question is an extension of that one: [Immutable numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541324/immutable-numpy-array)

This code prints False, because even though `a` is immutable, `b` is not.

```
a = np.arange(10)
a.setflags(write=False)
b = a[1:]
b[1] = -1
print a == np.arange(10)
```

Which defeats the purpose of having readonly arrays in the first place. Is there a way to inherit readonlibility in numpy?

Comment: When I run that code, `b` is also non-writable, and the comparison works as expected. You could always try `np.equal`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get:

```
>>> b[1] = -1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: array is not writeable
```

This is with numpy 1.6.0 (on Python 2.6.2).  Possibly this was a bug that was fixed, or a regression - what version of numpy are you using?