# Setting a class attribute of the type dict as private in python

Tags: python, attributes, protected

I have the following situation (here a bit simplified):

```
class MyClass():
    tables = dict
    matrices = dict

    def __init__(self, table_A, table_B=None, A=None, B=None)
        self.tables = {'A': table_A, 'B': table_B}
        self.matrices = {'A': A, 'B': B}
```

Now do not want my matrices to able to be set manually. Therefore my approach was to simply set them protected.

```
class MyClass():
    tables = dict
    _matrices = dict

    def __init__(self, table_A, table_B=None, A=None, B=None)
        self.tables = {'A': table_A, 'B': table_B}
        self._matrices = {'A': A, 'B': B}

    @property
        def matrices(self):
            # Getter function of the matrices attribute.
            return self._matrices

    @matrices.setter
    def matrices(self, value):
        raise AttributeError('The matrices of the model cannot be set manually!')
```

If I now initalize an instance myclass of the MyClass class it results in the following situation:
`myclass.matrices = 3`  (raises my AttributeError from the setter method - this is what I want)
`myclass.matrices['A'] = 3` (no warning, just does what I wrote - I would like to avoid this!)

What should I do in a situation like this in your opinion?

I already thought of two workarounds:

1. extend my number of attributes, have single attributes for each former dict entry (_matrix_A, _matrix_B) and loose the advantage of the
   stucture given by the dict.
2. write an additional class MatrixClass and amending my base class MyClass

   ````
        _A = np.Array
        _B = np.Array

        def __init__(self, A, B):
            self._A = A
            self._B = B

        @property
        def A(self):
            # Getter function of the A attribute.
            return self._A

        @A.setter
        def A(self, dictionary):
            raise AttributeError('The matrix A cannot be set manually.')

    class MyClass():
        tables = dict
        _matrices = MatrixClass

        def __init__(self, table_A, table_B=None, A=None, B=None)
            self.tables = {'A': table_A, 'B': table_B}
            self._matrices = MatrixClass(A, B)

        @property
            def matrices(self):
                # Getter function of the matrices attribute.
                return self._matrices

        @matrices.setter
        def matrices(self, value):
            raise AttributeError('The matrices of the model cannot be set manually!')```
   ````

What would you recommend to be a kind of pretty solution to this?
Thank you!

Comment: If you're not the only user of your code, tell other ones not to change the values manually? We're among adults...

Comment: @ThierryLathuille if being an adult implyed doing things always very rationally and mindfully (and reading the docs), I would agree. Sadly, based on personal life experience I have to highly doubt that this implication holds.

Comment: If you are writing something that may be used but a lot of others, then I would not assume that everyone is reading the documentation. If I want a property to be not writable since the user should not be able to change it and this is not possible, then I would have to say that the language is lacking something important.

Comment: `tables = dict` should be `tables: dict` otherwise you are setting the value of the class attribute to dict constructor instead of specifying the type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the library `frozendict` which provides a immutable dictionnary. I would have done something like this :

```bash
pip install frozendict
```

```py
from frozendict import frozendict

class MyClass():

    def __init__(self, A=None, B=None):
        self._matrices = frozendict({'A': A, 'B': B})

    @property
    def matrices(self):
        # Getter function of the matrices attribute.
        return self._matrices

    @matrices.setter
    def matrices(self, value):
        raise AttributeError('The matrices of the model cannot be set manually!')
```

Then, if I try to change the value of key `A` in `matrices`, like :

```py
c = MyClass()
c.matrices["A"] = 2
```

... an error will be raised:

```py
TypeError: 'frozendict' object doesn't support item assignment
```

Comment: I guess we would also want the values of the dictionary to be immutable.  For example, if `A` and `B` are numpy arrays, the constructor could make them unwritable (or copy them and make the copies unwriteable): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541324/immutable-numpy-array

Comment: @thomask as far as I played around with this until now, this seems to be a quite elegant option. Thanks a lot for your quick answer! :)